# Multiple GeoJSON filter based on properties in Leaflet by button -- work with only first Property

Tags: leaflet, geojson, filter

I am trying to filter my geoJSON layer (school) based on those properties:

1. Type ( primary - preparatory - high )
2. Time ( day - night - alltime  )
3. Gender ( male - female )

**What I need :**
After user choose the properties and click the filter button
school appear depend on the the properties.

**But that happens:**
Filter button works just with "Type ( primary - preparatory - high )"
and if I uncheck  other  properties  There is no effect

***This photo for map and chekbox***

[image]

**All Code in**

*codepen* : https://codepen.io/A_Abdelwahed/pen/BaKJEGy

*jsfiddle* : https://jsfiddle.net/Ahmed_Abdelwahed/0yxtoh8w/

**HTML code for input**

```html
<label> School type</label><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschooltype' value='primary' checked>primary<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschooltype'  value='preparatory' checked>preparatory<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschooltype'  value='high' checked>high<br><br>

<label> School time</label><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschooltime' value='day' checked>day<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschooltime'   value='night' checked>night<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschooltime'   value='all-time' checked>all time<br><br>

<label> School gender</label><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschoolgender'   value='male' checked>male<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='fltschoolgender'   value='female' checked>female<br>

<button id="btnProjectFilter" >Filter</button>
```

**Script code is**

```js
var schoolLayer = L.geoJson(schoolGeoJson, {
    pointToLayer: schoolMarker,
    filter: filterhotels
}).addTo(map);

function filterhotels(json) {
    var schooltypeFilter = [];
    $("input[name=fltschooltype]").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            schooltypeFilter.push(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("input[name=fltschooltime]").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            schooltypeFilter.push(this.value);
        }
    });

    $("input[name=fltschoolgender]").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            schooltypeFilter.push(this.value);
        }
    });

    var att = json.properties;
    switch (att.Type) {
        case "primary":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('primary') >= 0);
            break;
        case "preparatory":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('preparatory') >= 0);
            break;
        case "high":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('high') >= 0);
            break;
    }

    var att = json.properties;
    switch (att.Time) {
        case "day":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('day') >= 0);
            break;
        case "night":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('night') >= 0);
            break;
        case "all-time":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('all-time') >= 0);
            break;
    }

    var att = json.properties;
    switch (att.Gender) {
        case "male":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('male') >= 0);
            break;
        case "female":
            return (schooltypeFilter.indexOf('female') >= 0);
            break;
    }
}
$("#btnProjectFilter").click(function () {
    schoolLayer.clearLayers();
    schoolLayer.addData(schoolGeoJson);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a GIS question, but pure JS one, but anyway ...

In your filter logic you return true/false value immediately when first condition is satisfied, and so the other two conditions remain untested. You also don't need switch statement for attribute values, attribute value can be directly used in `.indexOf(...)` array method.

Your filter should then look something like this:

```
function filterhotels (json) {
  var schooltypeFilter = [];
  $("input[name=fltschooltype]").each(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      schooltypeFilter.push(this.value);
    }
  }); 

  $("input[name=fltschooltime]").each(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      schooltypeFilter.push(this.value);
    }
  }); 

  $("input[name=fltschoolgender]").each(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      schooltypeFilter.push(this.value);
    }
  }); 

  var att = json.properties;
  var cond1 = (schooltypeFilter.indexOf(att.Type) >= 0);
  var cond2 = (schooltypeFilter.indexOf(att.Time) >= 0);
  var cond3 = (schooltypeFilter.indexOf(att.Gender) >= 0);
  
  return(cond1 & cond2 & cond3);
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Many thanks for the clear explanation and your time